# Multiple selectors using this and variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a quick tab section on a website. On click, jQuery grabs the data-slide and uses that info to find a matching ID and applies a class.

```
<div class="service-link" data-slide="#post-123">Click Me</div>
```

'target' does not get the active class applied to it when I use 'this' and target on the same line.

```
$(this, target).addClass("active");
```

It works if I use two lines. Anybody know why I cant use one line?

```
$(this).addClass("active");
$(target).addClass("active");
```

Full Working Script -

```
$(".service-link").click(function(){
    var target = $(this).data("slide");
    $(".service-type-slide, .service-link").removeClass("active");
    $(target).addClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
})`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method to achieve this:

```
$(this).add(target).addClass("active");
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/geacgv08/)

---

You were trying:

```
$(this, target).addClass("active");
```

which is basically equivalent to using:

```
$(target).find(this).addClass("active");
```

That's why it wasn't working.

You can see an example demonstrating this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/humdssLp/).

Answer (score 0):

I think that:

```
   $(this, target)
```

will try to find the node element (which *this* refer to)  inside the target context.  but it wont find it, because target does not contains that element